# django project does not write to file and there is no error, the file does not appear

Tags: django

I'm trying to write to a file and django doesn't do it. There is no error of any kind but the file does not appear. Using the process monitor I don't see any attempt to write.
In a python file the same code works fine.

Test performed:

```
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class TestWrite(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'test.html'

    with open(r'd:\djangotest.txt', "w") as fo:
        fo.write('test')
        fo.close()
```

I did the test with Popen and it doesn't work either.

```
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
returncode = p.returncode
```

In the case of Popen I used pg_dump.exe and in stderr I got the result of the program running correctly but no file anywhere.

It doesn't matter which path you select to write, inside the project, outside of it, ect. the file does not appear.

I don't know if it's important, but I did the tests in pycharm.

Comment: Recently I also faced the same error. I was saving files in media dir of project and it was't in .gitignore so pyCharm explicitly asked about saving the files which I denied and the file wasn't appearing + no error thrown by django. Check if this is your case.

Comment: This is not the case, I am executing the class through the browser.